# Angular 14: How to make routing for multi applications project

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, angular14

I have created an angular workspace with parent and child applications. Folder structure looks next way:

```
client\
+ projects\
|  +sub-app1 <- child application #1
|  +sub-app2 <- child application #2
...
+ src\ <- parent application here
```

I made next routing parameters for parent and child applications:

Parent app app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'sub-app1', component: SubApp1Module},
  {path: 'sub-app2', component: SubApp2Module},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

Sub-app1 app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'sub-app1', redirectTo: 'sub-app1/component1', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'sub-app1/component1', component: Component1Component},
  {path: 'sub-app1/component2', component: Component2Component}  
];
```

Sub-app2 app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'sub-app2', redirectTo: 'sub-app2/component1', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'sub-app2/component1', component: Component1Component},
  {path: 'sub-app2/component2', component: Component2Component}  
];
```

Everything works and I can be navigated from paren application inside to child application. Problem appears when I manually typed in `https://localhost:4200/sub-app1`, it takes me back to the home page `https://localhost:4200`, but doesn't redirect me to the **login** page. In console I have next error:
[image]

I'm scratching my head and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in order to make it work and handle wrong urls.

Comment: If you are trying to access `localhost:4200/sub-app1`, the application will try to load `SubApp1Module`, which is not a Component (hence the error), you don't need those 2 routes in app's app-routing-module. I think this will solve your issue

Comment: Yes, removing child routes from the parent routing did help. Another question, how I can capture bad url in this case? Example: `localhost:4200/sub-app123`

Comment: You can create a wildcard route: `{path: '**', redirectTo: 'path'}` and it will redirect the user to whatever path you want in case they are trying to access a page that does not exist.

Comment: Yes, by if I create a wildcard in the parent routing file `{path: '**', redirectTo: 'error'}`, then it can't recognize child routes and sends me to the error page no matter what. Example: I tried to navigate to `localhost:4200/sub-app1/component1` and it sends me to `localhost:4200/error`

Comment: Indeed, because in your application, the main routing module doesn't know that there are children components that have their routing, that's why (usually) there is only one routing module in the main component, and then the children routes are nested. If I were you, I would put all the routes inside the main app's app-routing-module and, at the end, I would add the wildcard route. I would suggest you take a look at this https://angular.io/guide/router, especially the part where they are persenting the `Nesting routes`

Comment: Yes, it will resolve the problem. I thought that because the project contains sub-applications that can be built and deployed separately, then sub-applications should contain it's own routing information and be injected into parent application "somehow"...